# php - back to posts link not HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php

I've got a little problem i want link "<< Back to posts" on my blog but I have no idea how to do this cause most of results in google shows the example of `"javascript:history.go(-1)"` or `"javascript:history.back()"` but if I'll redirect to my post from google link will take me to google site not to list of posts.

is there a simple answer to my question in `PHP`?

url to post on my site looks like this

for example if we have 16 posts and limit of posts is 15 per page

> www.mysite.com/?article_id=1

it points to first article wich on posts list in on the first page with url

> www.mysite.com/?articles_page=2

but if article url will look like this

> www.mysite.com/?article_id=16

"Back" anchor point to

> www.mysite.com/?articles_page=1

etc.

this blog is my own project cause I'm learning PHP

Comment: In the particular scenario, instead of using `HTTP_REFERRER`, save the desired URL in the `$_SESSION` variable, and on submit, redirect the user to this particular URL.

Comment: Which software are you using to power your blog?

Comment: this is my own project cause i'm learning PHP :)

Comment: you have to track the current pageid and on click of browser back button you have to redirect the user to previous page [like if you are on article 16 of page 3 and on clicking back you will get redirected to page 2]. you can use session also as Mr. Alien said.

Comment: you mean count like in pagination script?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for my question

this is the code
the variable `$id` is the id of the actually viewed article

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS last FROM articles WHERE published=1"); //we are counting only published articles

$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$counter = 0; //this is the counter of loop
do {
    $id++; //incrementation of viewed article
    $counter++; //loop iterations
} while($res['last'] >= $id);

$total_pages = ceil($counter / 15); //counting the position of article on articles list pages. I'm displaing 15 articles per page.


    return  '<a href="/?articles_page='.$total_pages.'" id="dark"> Back to articles list</a>';
```

and that's all maybe it'll help someone else.